# Multiple upload images is not save using loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter Framework. I have a form where user select model name and select image for icon, and two more fields are in it. These two fields and image for icon are repeating fields when user click a add more button as I show a form code

```
<div class="box box-primary ">
<div class="box-header with-border">
  <h3 class="box-title">Add Repair Type</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <form method="post" class="parsley-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Models *</font>
                         <select name="modelid" id="modelid" class="form-control" required="">
                            <?php  if($get_models) { 
                                foreach($get_models as $model) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$model['id']?>"><?=$model['model_name']?></option>
                            <?php } } ?>
                         </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row0">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="table-active">
                         <tr>
                            <th>Reapir Type Icon *</th>
                            <th>Repair Type *</th>
                            <th>Price *</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="dynamic_field">
                        <tr id="row">
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="repair_type[0]" class="form-control" required="">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="repair_type[0][repairtype]" class="form-control" required="">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="repair_type[0][price]" class="form-control" required="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="javascript:void(0);"
                                       id="addup">
                                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                        <?php echo lang('Add More...');?>
                                    </a>
             <br><br>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>panel/repair_type" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fas fa-reply"></i> Back</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>   Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    var i=0;  
    $('#addup').click(function(){ 
       i++;  
       
       var data = '<tr id="row'+i+'">';
      data += '<td><input type="file" name="repair_type['+i+']" class="form-control" required=""></td>';
      data += '<td><input type="text" name="repair_type['+i+'][repairtype]" class="form-control" required=""></td>';
      data += '<td><input type="text" name="repair_type['+i+'][price]" class="form-control" required=""></td>';
      data += '</tr>';
      
       $('#dynamic_field').append(data);    
      });     
      }); 
   </script>
```

**Controller file**

```
public function add() {

    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $data = array(
            'fk_modelid' => $this->input->post('modelid'),
            'sub_id' => NULL
        );


         $this->db->insert('repair_type', $data);
         $insertedID = $this->db->insert_id();
         if($insertedID)
          {
            if(isset($_FILES["repair_type"]) )
              {
                foreach ($_FILES["repair_type"]["name"] as $key => $image) 
                {

                  $_FILES['images']['name']  = $_FILES["repair_type"]['name'][$key];
                  $_FILES['images']['type']  = $_FILES["repair_type"]['type'][$key];
                  $_FILES['images']['tmp_name']  = $_FILES["repair_type"]['tmp_name'][$key];
                  $_FILES['images']['error']= $_FILES["repair_type"]['error'][$key];
                  $_FILES['images']['size']  =   $_FILES["repair_type"]['size'][$key];

                  if($_FILES['images']['name'] != "")
                  {
                    $response = $this->upload_image1("images","assets/uploads/repair_type");
                    if($response["error"] == 0)
                    {
                        $rt_insertarray["repair_type"][$key]["image"] = "repair_type/".$response["upload_data"]["file_name"];
                          
                    }
                  }

                } 
              }
         
            foreach($this->input->post("repair_type") as $repair_type)
            {
              $rt_insertarray = array(
                  "repairtype" => $repair_type['repairtype'],
                  "price" => $repair_type['price'],
                  "sub_id" => $insertedID
                );
            }
          }
          $this->db->insert_batch('repair_type', $rt_insertarray);
           $this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Repair Type added successfully." );
           //redirect('panel/repair_type', 'refresh');
    }
    $this->data["get_models"] = $this->models_model->get_models();
   $this->render('repair_type/add',$this->data);
}
```

Issue is that using for loop to uploading multiple files and files record is not saving into database

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_FILES['repair_type'])){
    foreach($_FILES['repair_type']['name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $fieldVal = $_FILES['repair_type']['name'][$key];
        if($fieldVal!="") { 
            $_FILES['image']['name']     = $_FILES['repair_type']['name'][$key]; 
            $_FILES['image']['type']     = $_FILES['repair_type']['type'][$key]; 
            $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['repair_type']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
            $_FILES['image']['error']     = $_FILES['repair_type']['error'][$key]; 
            $_FILES['image']['size']     = $_FILES['repair_type']['size'][$key]; 
            $filename = "REPAIR-TYPE-".date('dmY').time(); 
            $image_config = array(
                'upload_path' => './images/Repair',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
                'max_size' => '8048',
                'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
                'file_name' => $filename,
                'overwrite' => FALSE
            );
            $this->load->library('Upload',$image_config);
            $this->upload->initialize($image_config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) { 
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else  {
                $image_data=$this->upload->data();
                $filename = $image_data['file_name'];
                
            }
            $rt_insertarray[$key]['repair_type'] =  $filename;
        }
    }
}

    foreach($this->input->post("repair_type") as $key => $val){
        $rt_insertarray[$key]= array(
           "repairtype" => $val,
           "price" => $this->input->post('price')[$key],
           "sub_id" => $insertedID
         );
      }
      $this->db->insert_batch('repair_type', $rt_insertarray);
```

Comment: Array fields are not defined properly according to the indexing due to this it is unable to insert data using 'insert_batch' operation